# is there mention in the Vention in the Vedas of the significance of Kamada Ekadashsi?

Tags: ekadashi

i read that any sin, even the worst is forgivable with fasting on this day. I just learned this today, I felt a very unpleasent. Karma from a past life which I recognize as a need to atone for past life actions. I am Sanyasi, which too is a recent thing. I learned of and observed Chaitra Ekadashi - which was my first. I'm an American living and working in America and one of my biggest challenges is proper pronunciation for the Mantras I am learning. Thank you.

Comment: Not in the Vedas but regarding Vratas, fasting etc. we find information in the Puranas. Mahabharata also gives info on Ekadashi fasting.